# Why are these LEDs listed as 3W when the forward voltage is 2.4V, and forward current is 700mA?

Tags: led, power, watts

The title of this listing says 3W:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/50PCS-3W-RED-80lm-640nm-LED-Plant-Glow-Light-Emitter-with-20mm-star-base-/221518318191?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3393854a6f

But the specs that follow show a forward voltage (max) of 2.4V and forward current of 700mA. Wouldn't the power in this case be 2.4V * 0.7A = 1.68W and not 3W?

Comment: Seems more like a question that is related to marketing rather than electronics design.  Is there some way you could re-word this so that there is some sort of technical implication of designing for 1.68W instead of 3W?

Comment: Do you have a datasheet? It's likely max pulse power at 10% duty cycle or something similar.

Comment: I always ask questions of the seller if they advertise anything that way...

Comment: Don't buy anything that doesn't have a proper pdf data sheet is my policy.

Comment: The only information I have is from the ebay listing itself. I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing something about how I was doing my calculation, since my result was not 3W.

Comment: @snapfractalpop  For future reference.  EE.SE is not a volunteer help desk for eBay sellers, who don't provide datasheets.  I'm not too enthused about having every item made in Shenzhen and listed on eBay go through EE.SE and remain here for posterity.  With a context like this you can try your luck in EE.SE chat.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I am fairly new to electronics, so I wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong in my calculations, or if I was missing something. That being said, I understand your point. I'll check out EE.SE chat. On the plus side, I did actually receive a lot of useful information in comments / answers.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely the maximum TDP (Thermal Design Power) of the LED, given the substrate/heatsink the actual diode is mounted to.

You should probably contact the seller though, since they might have just screwed up.